# How to Add new data to a array list via intents

Tags: java, android, arrays, arraylist, android-intent

In my app you can create a work project, you add client name, budget etc.
for UI purposes a staff member addition is on a seprate activity

Now My problem is that I pass the data in a Array between the activities via INTENT
that data is then displayed in a listview

Now the thing I am struggling with is that every time I want to add NEW data to the Array, The Array  goes back to blank and then only displays the new data

So basically you add the Staff member data to an array, it goes to the other activity and passes that array via intent and Displays in a ListView

But it only displays the new data in the array

What I want to achieve is that the older data in the array must not disapear and the new data must just be added to the array and not create a new array
therby displaying the old and the new data

**Activity 1 Code**

This Passes the data to the other activity aswell as starts the other activity

```
      AddStaff.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
                @Override
                public void onClick(View view) {
                    MemberBudgetPassData= MemberBudget.getText().toString();
                    BudgetHoursPassData = budgetHours.getText().toString();

                    StaffList = Client + Rates + Staff + BudgetHoursPassData + MemberBudgetPassData;
                    StaffArray.add(StaffList);

                    PassData();


                    }



            });
 public  void PassData(){
        Intent GoToReport=new Intent(getApplicationContext(), createProject.class);
        MemberBudgetPassData= MemberBudget.getText().toString();
        BudgetHoursPassData = budgetHours.getText().toString();
        Toasty.info(popupActivity.this, StaffArray.toString(),Toasty.LENGTH_LONG).show();

        GoToReport.putStringArrayListExtra("Array",StaffArray);




       startActivity(GoToReport);

            Animatoo.animateCard(popupActivity.this);

    }
```

**Activity 2**

Here it retrieves the data and diplays it in a listview

```
Array = new ArrayList<>();
    Array = getIntent().getStringArrayListExtra("Array");



   final ArrayAdapter arrayAdapter =new ArrayAdapter<>
                (this, android.R.layout.simple_list_item_1, Array);
        if (Array == null)
        {
            Toasty.info(createProject.this,"Select a Staff Memebr",Toasty.LENGTH_LONG).show();
        }
        else
        {
            StaffListView.setAdapter(arrayAdapter);
        }
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I use Gson library like this situation. Firstly, you should use model class and then pass model class or Arraylist object as String. For example;

Activity 1

```
public  void PassData(){
    Intent GoToReport=new Intent(getApplicationContext(), createProject.class);
    MemberBudgetPassData= MemberBudget.getText().toString();
    BudgetHoursPassData = budgetHours.getText().toString();
    Toasty.info(popupActivity.this, StaffArray.toString(),Toasty.LENGTH_LONG).show();


    GoToReport.putString("Array",new Gson.toJson(StaffArray));

    startActivity(GoToReport);
    Animatoo.animateCard(popupActivity.this);
}
```

Activity 2

```
Type listType = new TypeToken<ArrayList<StaffArray>>(){}.getType();
Array = new ArrayList<>();
Array = new Gson.fromJson(getIntent().getString("Array", listType));

final ArrayAdapter arrayAdapter =new ArrayAdapter<>
                (this, android.R.layout.simple_list_item_1, Array);
    if (Array == null)
    {
        Toasty.info(createProject.this,"Select a Staff Memebr",Toasty.LENGTH_LONG).show();
    }
    else
    {
        StaffListView.setAdapter(arrayAdapter);
    }
```

Finally, don't remember add Gson library in gradle file.

```
implementation 'com.google.code.gson:gson:2.8.6'
```

Comment: Thanks Dude, Works well, I also have another method I figured out before seeing your answer I just pass the data back and forth via intents but your answer works better